# Unit test method with reference to environment.ts using Jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm (very) new to writing unit tests and I'm wondering how I should approach testing a static method that constructs our API endpoints based on what the properties are set to in our `environment.ts` file.

The `environment.ts` file changes with the environment, so I'm curious how I would accommodate for that in my test.

Does my method need to be refactored to make this easier to test? For example, instead of implicitly referencing environment.endpoint, instead pass-in environment as a argument? Would I mock the environment.ts file?

Any suggestions would be helpful.

```
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';

export class Utilities {

  public static constructAPIEndpoint(): string {
    const hostname: string = environment.endpoint;
    const protocol: string = environment.local ? 'http:' : 'https:';

    return `${protocol}//${hostname}/`;
  }
}
```

environments.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  local: false,
  hostname: 'localhost',
  showLogs: true,
  endpoint: 'foo-dev-graphapp.com',
  appInsights: {
    instrumentationKey: '123'
  }
};
```

jasmine test:

```
  import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';

  it('constructAPIEndpoint() it should construct an endpoint based on environment.ts', () => {
    const endpoint: string = Utilities.constructAPIEndpoint();

    /// THIS DOESN'T SEEM - having to recreate logic inside constructAPIEndpoint()
    const protocol: string = environment.local ? 'http:' : 'https';



    expect(endpoint).toEqual(`${protocol}//${environment.endpoint}`);


  });
```

Comment: Are you injecting environment into your component with dependency injection?

Comment: @dmcgrandle not injecting environment, just importing it into `.ts` file. The file I'm testing is a simple utilities file with a bunch of static methods. My co-worker suggested that we mock the environment file, but if the file changes per environment, then we can't expect the endpoint be consistent.

Comment: Found similar SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49091393/how-to-mock-environment-files-import-in-unit-tests

Comment: Yes, that's why I was asking about DI - it's the more "angular way" of doing things, and also lends itself to better testing, as you found out.  :)